# #reactjs Failed to compile

Tags: reactjs

./src/App.js
  Line 5:7:  Parsing error: A class name is required

3 | import Header from './Header'
  4 |

> 5 | class extends App Component{
>       |       ^
>     6 |   return (
>     7 |     
>     8 |

Comment: Please provide some more code so we can understand the problem. This information is useless without more code.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax has a problem.

You have to replace

```
class extends App Component
```

to

```
class App extends Component
```